# How can I increase speed of vehicles in Veins?

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

I am using OMNeT++ 5.4.1, Veins 7.4.1, and SUMO 0.30.0.

As the maximum speed of vehicles in Veins is 13.99, I really want to increase it up to 33. How can I do it? is it possible in Veins or should I do it in SUMO?

Comment: I changed erlangen.rou.xml and set max speed to 33 but unfortunately it did not work out and its speed is still 0 up to 13.99.

Comment: I searched on google for this and the same question was asked in 2014, and there was a response from someone asking ```"Do you consider if there is a limited speed for road definition?"```, but the OP didn't reply. Maybe it is something to check out?

Answer (score 1):

You may need to modify the network. Probably the vehicles are only allowed to drive 50 km/h (about 13.99 m/s considering the deviations allowed by the models) on the streets you are looking at. Use SUMO's netedit to edit the maximum edge speeds.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mr Michael. however I was changed it just up to 27

Comment: Maybe the road is too short or there is too much traffic? You can try to specify a departSpeed.